# How to change the x-coordinate in the loop?

Tags: python

I have created a program in Python to place some field images next to each other.

I made a class called field here:

```py
class Field(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,group):
      super().__init__(group)
      self.image = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\*****\\Documents\\Python\\BuildATown\\graphics\\field.png').convert_alpha()
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Then I want to add the image(s) in six different places in order like so:

```py
camera = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(6):
    x=50
    y=200
    Field((x,y), camera)
    x=x+200
```

But when I run the code, the field(s) are all in the same place on top of one another. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code

```
for i in range(6):
    x=50
    y=200
    Field((x,y), camera)
    x=x+200
```

You are doing the whole `x` and `y` thing 6 times, however you are doing the exact same thing every time. In all 6 loops, first you say `x` equals 50 and then later add an extra `200` which makes it `250`.

If you want `x` for example to be `50, 250, 450, 650, 850, 1050` so increase by 200 every loop. Do something like this:

```
for i in range(6):
    x=50 + (200 * i)
    y=200
    Field((x,y), camera)
```